# Laravel 7 error when adding foreign key to Users table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-migrations

using Laravel 7 and MySQL, I'm trying to add a foreign key to the Users table generated by the Laravel Auth system...

First, i've created my new table user_type and then, on another migration, I'm trying to add the foreign key to the users table, but then I get the error.

Here a gist with the migrations and the error: https://gist.github.com/jdalri/73cee7a00c513c93afd5186ca27d74a4

I've also tried using

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_type_id');

$table->foreign('user_type_id')->references('id')->on('user_type');
```

but got the same error.

Thanks

Comment: I saw your code, here you want to make a relationship from `user` to `user_type` table. But when your system make relationship on `user` with `user_type` table. On that time `user_type` table doesn't exist. so you get this error. For this you need to create first `user_type` table, then you can make relationship from `user` table. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax is right but what is you missing is the foreign key doesnt have a default value(that exists in user_type table) or its not nullable. and its because there no record in  `user_type` table with null value so if you reset the database with `php artisan migrate:fresh` that will work or make this column nullable.

Comment: I had already a user on the Users table, so the php artisan migrate:fresh command fixed the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_type_id')->nullable();

$table->foreign('user_type_id')->references('id')->on('user_type');
```

That works because literally the error is explaining that before you add content to the users table, user_type_id must have content. If you null it, it will work but its not a good idea to do so. I advise you if user_types are not much, create them as enum and choose the default one.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a link to Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_type_id')->constrained('user_type');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no primary key for `AddUserTypeToUsersTable`

Try this

```
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_type_id');
        $table->foreign('user_type_id')->references('id')->on('user_type');
    });
```

Comment: this migration is not for creating users table, its already been created look at migration name this migration just adding this column to exsisting users table