# Can't create foreign key on another table using ID of my users table [Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed]

Tags: migration, laravel-9

I was trying to create a comments table that was going to have a foreign key user_id that refferenced the "ID" on users table. But each time I ran my migration, I kept getting this error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `9anime`.`comments` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `comments` add constraint `comments user_id foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

My users migration code

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My comments migration file

```
 Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
        });
```

When I run my migration, I get that error. I looked at my code and did not find anything wrong with it.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724135/15770919) suggested that the user_id be made nullable. I did that but it did not change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the users migration file, specifically this line

`$table->id();`

to

`$table->increments('id');`

then ran my migration and it worked